# how to create an alert prompt in the controller before redirecting to a new view?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

is it possible to create an alert prompt in the controller before redirecting to a new view? i want to make the users acknowledge a message in the current view before directing them to the next view

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using MvcApplication.Models;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.View(model);
    }

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

***// Here! create an alert with a close button using javascript and make the user acknowledge it by clicking a button and closing the alert before redirecting the user*** 

        if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

    return this.View(model);
}
```

Comment: Not directly, the controller is pure serverside in response to an http request. Your end response to this request is to redirect. Your options are to send a response back to the client that will have the javascript alert, which will, in turn, trigger another request-response cycle with the redirect. Another option would be to handle this client side before the initial request to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return from that method some View with the message, with a link and/or an auto-redirect.

It's not possible to "pause" the processing of the controllers to send messages back to the user!!

Comment: how do i do an auto re-direct in the view?

Comment: You can use a document.location with the desired url!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom ActionFilter and put this action filter on Controller's Action

```
public class CustomActionFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.StartupScript = "Your Message Goes here";
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Your javascript code on `_Layout` page as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
     alert('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.StartupScript)');
 </script>
```

You controller Action

```
 [CustomActionFilter]
 public ActionResult Helo(
 {
     //Some Stuff here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible to show (javascript)alert box from controller.
Just add below line to your controller.
Try with this it may help you.

```
return JavaScript(alert("Hello this is an alert"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it by using ViewBag in MVC. You could put your javascript code in a ViewBag like:

```
ViewBag.Javascript = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Your message');</script>";
```

and then navigate to your page.